# What is the time format used in Date constructor in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running Nodejs in Lambda in Sydney region. I have below code:

```
> d=new Date('2020-12-14T13:20:44.733Z')
2020-12-14T13:20:44.733Z
> d.getDate()
15
```

It creates a Date instance with a date string `2020-12-14T13:20:44.733Z`. But the date is translated to 15th of December not 14th. Does this mean the string `2020-12-14T13:20:44.733Z` representing UTC time?

Comment: Yes, importantly it ends with "Z", which stands for "Zulu time," which is indeed UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process that is carried out is described in the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format):

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format. The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

> **Z**  is the UTC offset representation specified as "Z" (for UTC with no offset) or an offset of either "+" or "-" followed by a time expression HH:mm (indicating local time ahead of or behind UTC, respectively)

So the trailing Z means the time passed into the Date constructor is in UTC, but `getDate` will give you the [*local* representation](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.getdate) of whatever time is in the Date object.